# Converting Date string with date format as "2015-11-09 06:54:00 UTC" to NSDate

Tags: ios, date, nsdate, nsdateformatter

The string I get from server is in the format like "2015-11-09 06:54:00 UTC" I want to convert

```
NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ";
NSDate* date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd MMM yyyy hh:mm a"];
NSString* formattedDate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
```

I tried with date formatter to be     `dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ";`

Still I get the formatted date as nil.

I don't understand how to convert this string to a proper NSDate. Please suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the below code snippet;

```
NSString *dateString = @"2015-11-09 06:54:00 UTC";
NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z";
NSDate* date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd MMM yyyy hh:mm a"];
NSString* formattedDate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
NSLog(@"Formatted Date: %@",formattedDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

I could say "try the code below", but that is useless.

Look at your formatting string. It says what the date formatter expects in the string.

Look at your date string.

Compare them. They don't match. The 'T' in the formatting string isn't some kind of black magic. It means "I expect a letter T in the date string". There is no letter T in the date string, that's why it doesn't work.

Read Apple's documentation carefully, and take note of the bit where it refers to the Unicode standard. And read that document at www.unicode.org carefully - There is a HUGE difference between yyyy and YYYY, and between MM and MMM, and between HH and hh, and if you don't read this and learn this, you cannot write code that gives the desired result.

Comment: Well 'T' in the Formatter does not mean that Letter T should be in the dateString. The T is just a literal to separate the date from the time, and the Z means "Zulu time" (UTC).